# Cannot connect to wifi and ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I am using windows 10 and a new acer laptop.I have tried troubleshooting and it diagnoses as no valid IP address. I don't know how to fix the problem. I have also noted that other laptops are connected to these WiFi and Ethernet when i can't connect.

Comment: Is DHCP service running properly in your computer ? Check your router for DHCP pool size to make sure you aren't out of IP's

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output from `ipconfig /all` run in a `cmd` window.

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver from [Acer](http://www.acer.ae/ac/en/AE/content/drivers) if there's no Windows 10 driver, use Windows 8/8.1 driver instead.